# How to crawl a site from multiple countries?

Tags: web-crawler

I'm in the US, and doing some lightweight crawling of a site that offers different versions depending on the country of access.

What is the best way to crawl from multiple countries? Is there a proxy service I could route my http requests through? Or will I need to rent lightweight VMs in each country and install my own proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

Well i use for this curl, if your main programming language is php, you can do that like this on your servers:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '195.175.37.72:80')
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

In the internet a lot of free proxy servers use google. Some guys give you access to proxy for money, but they service is better. Of course you can buy machines in another countries but the way i do it is cheaper and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free web proxy like www.hidemyass.com - but dont expect too much off it.

There are also some free and public proxies out there, just use the search engine of your choice to find them. (or look here http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)

Or use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) (though i'm not sure if you can choose a specific exit node).

If you really considered renting VMs you could also subscibe to a professional proxy service (that means more bandwidth etc.)